# Huwai E303C is not working

Tags: 12.04, networking, hardware

```
Device - Huwai E303C
Network - AIRTEL
Location - Bangalore India
OS - Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

Have tried following but didn't work :

1. Installing Linux driver which comes along with Device
2. Tried with following commands on terminal,  but didn't work

   `sudo apt-get remove usb-modeswitch usb-modeswitch-data`

   `sudo apt-get install usb-modeswitch`

Please could someone help me by explaining how I could connect to the E303C device.

Answer (score 0):

It should work without installing any driver, Atfirst Unistall the Driver, than reinstall usb-modeswitch,usb-modeswitch-data, Install http://linuxonly.ru/cms/page.php?7 "Modem Manager Gui" for chking balance, SMS etc.